# Select columns from a table and count a value from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, select

I have the following tables:

**table_user**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Arnold |
| 2 | Wesley |
| 3 | Abel |
| 4 | Harry |
| 5 | Cristiano |

**table_post**

fk_user is from user who created the post

| id | fk_user | title | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | Movie | I like horror movies |
| 2 | 4 | Music | Music is essential to my days |
| 3 | 4 | Soccer | The World Cup is coming! |

**table_post_like**

fk_user is from user who liked the post

| fk_post | fk_user |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |

I need to select all posts liked by user Arnold (id 1) with all columns from **tb_post** and number of likes. The result would be something like that:

| id | fk_user | title | description | likes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | Movie | I like horror movies | 4 |
| 3 | 4 | Soccer | The World Cup is coming! | 2 |

I tried this but the number of likes is not correct

```
SELECT TP.*, COUNT(TPL.fk_post) AS likes
FROM table_post AS TP
RIGHT JOIN  table_post_like AS TPL
ON TP.id = TPL.fk_post
WHERE TPL.fk_user = 1
GROUP BY TP.id
```

Comment: FYI, when you use aggregate function, all selected columns must be in the group by list

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
SELECT table_post.*, t.occurence FROM table_post
JOIN
(SELECT fk_post, COUNT(fk_user) as occurence FROM table_post_like WHERE fk_post IN(SELECT fk_post FROM table_post_like WHERE fk_user = 1)
GROUP BY fk_post) as t ON t.fk_post = table_post.id
```

Query above returns the value as expected

| id | fk_user | title | description | likes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | Movie | I like horror movies | 4 |
| 3 | 4 | Soccer | The World Cup is coming! | 2 |

Check db fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qiSDaTA9xiR7oss88Nr8Vc/1)